# Watermark layer added text gets flipped to opposite direction when adding to video

Tags: iphone, ios, calayer, avplayerlayer

I am trying to add a watermark layer(image / text) to a video using the source code from the below link but when added with gesture recognizers to resize the watermark and while exporting, the position and direction of the added watermark changes in opposite direction on the converted movie file kindly help me to resolve this issue.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVSimpleEditoriOS/Introduction/Intro.html

[image: original added watermark and converted video watermarks]

Answer (score 0):

geometryFlipped = YES. This is will sort out this issue.